# The behavior of unparenthesized expressions containing both '.' and '+'/'-' will change in PHP 8: '+'/'-' will take a higher precedence

Tags: php, php-7.4

```
$date1 = date('d M Y', strtotime('+' . $i + 1 . 'month'));
```

This error pops sometimes even I am not calling this function at that point but it works fine when I refresh the page, it seems like some warning.

Comment: As the warning suggests, try to add parenthesis to `$i+1` so `($i+1)`

Answer (score 8):

The issue is that your expression is

```
'+' . $i + 1 . 'month'
```

First, it evaluates the leftmost operand, which is `'+'`. Then it appends `$i` to that `String`, resulting in something like '`+123'`. And then it tries to numerically add `1` to that `String`, but that will fail, because PHP cannot convert the lefthand-side to a number. In order to solve it, you will need to evaluate `$i + 1` first and then evaluate your `String`.

You can do so implicitly:

```
$date1 = date('d M Y', strtotime('+' . ($i + 1) . 'month'));
```

or explicitly:

```
$monthOffset = $i + 1;
$date1 = date('d M Y', strtotime('+' . $monthOffset . 'month'));
```

Comment: It won't fail to convert `'+123'` to a number, that's a perfectly valid number as far as PHP is concerned. In fact this will work just fine because strtotime will parse `'123month'` the same as `'+123month'`. `var_dump(strtotime('123month'),strtotime('+123month')); int(2002562089) int(2002562089)`

Answer (score 1):

PHP is complaining because what you wrote doesn't mean what you think it does, prior to PHP 8. (And because in most instances the code will behave incorrectly, though in your instance it works fine.)

As of PHP 8, it *does* mean what you think it does, but you might as well add parentheses anyway to make it clear.

```
$date1 = date('d M Y', strtotime('+' . $i + 1 . 'month'));
// prior to PHP 8, . and + have the same precedence, so this means:
$date1 = date('d M Y', strtotime((('+' . $i) + 1) . 'month'));
// for example, with $i=1:
$date1 = date('d M Y', strtotime(('+1' + 1) . 'month'));
$date1 = date('d M Y', strtotime(2 . 'month'));
$date1 = date('d M Y', strtotime('2month'));
```

However, you are seeing your code work just fine, because strtotime (at least as of PHP 7.4) doesn't care whether it sees '+2month' (as intended) or '2month'. The result of strtotime will be the same, and so `$date1` will also be the same.

The deprecation warning doesn't really apply to you, because the overall result will not change when the precedence of these operators does. But to silence the warning (and any confusion) you can always change it by adding parentheses, as the other answers have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using PHP 7.4, which marks certain things as deprecated.
These are not errors.
Manually add parentheses where appropriate.

Example:

```
$response = '1234567890';
$header = 'Content-length: ' . strlen($response) + 1;
header($header);
```

In PHP 5.6, $header would contain 1. In PHP 7.0 to 7.4, it would contain the same, but will also emit a deprecation warning. In PHP 8.0+, it will contain Content-length: 11.

We wrap the arithmetic expression in parentheses, so that to get the correct number is concatenated:

```
$response = '1234567890';
header('Content-length: ' . (strlen($response) + 1));
```

So, you can do so implicitly:

```
$date1 = date('d M Y', strtotime('+' . ($i + 1) . 'month'));
```